# How to run a command via elisp, completely ignoring its output and status? (fire and forget)

Tags: subprocess

Currently I'm using shell command - which makes a buffer, showing the output, sometimes locking emacs.

What is a good way to run a process that:

- Doesn't make a buffer.
- Doesn't lock emacs.
- Ignores the stdout/stderr.

Comment: `start-process` with `nil` for the buffer argument:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html

Comment: `async-shell-command` might be interesting as well. It should be trivial to write another interactive wrapper that doesn't create a buffer with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call-process`, despite normally being used for synchronous process calls:

```
call-process is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(call-process PROGRAM &optional INFILE DESTINATION DISPLAY &rest ARGS)

[...]
Insert output in DESTINATION before point[...]0 means discard and don't wait
[...]
If DESTINATION is 0, `call-process' returns immediately with value nil.
[...]
```

Comment: call-process requires commands to be split up. I ended up using: `(call-process-shell-command my_command nil 0)))))`